# How to control when to ask for notification permission with FCM plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic3, apple-push-notifications, cordova-plugin-fcm

In an Ionic 3 app, I am using the Cordova FCM plugin for notifications. I would like to ask for notification permission when my users click a button within the app.

But, now the app asks for notification on launch. I’d rather ask for notifications later. Not right away. I tested this on iOS devices only so far.

I am using the FCM plugin only in app.component.ts. FCM plugin code should run on the condition that a database variable exists and equals to a certain value. This value is changed in the app when the user clicks a button. I was hoping the the plugin would kick in when the button is clicked but not when the app starts. Here is my code. Please help!

**app.component.ts**

```
platform.ready().then(() => {

//START: notification operator    
const authListener=afAuth.authState.subscribe(user =>  {
if (user) {
this.userId = user.uid;
//check if user answered yes to the question asked after first clicking a follow button
firebase.database().ref(`/members/${this.userId}/notStats/`).on("value", res => {
if (res.exists()) {
if (res.val().notifAllowed == true ) {
//START: get device token and save in user members
fcm.getToken().then(token => {
   afDatabase.object(`/members/${this.userId}/notificationStatus/`).update({deviceToken: token});
});
//START: subscribe to notification listener
fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
if (data.wasTapped) {//Notification tapped by the user 
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
} else { //App was in foreground when notification was sent
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));}
});
} //end: if notifsAllowed saved in database as true
} //end: if exists
});//end: firebase listener   
authListener.unsubscribe();} else {authListener.unsubscribe();}});
//notification operator: END

});
```

How can I ask for notification permission when the button in the app is first clicked? I do not wish the app to ask for permission to send notifications on first launch. It makes for terrible user experience, asking for permission at the beginning before users even get to see the app.

Thanks!